# In TypeScript how do you get a date from an integer?

Tags: typescript

JavaScript

```
>> var d = Date(1627646185);
undefined
>> d.toString();
"Fri Jul 30 2021 12:17:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)"
```

TypeScript

```
let d = Date(1627646185);
return d.toISOString();
```

> `error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`

​How can you get TypeScript to show the actual date and time from one of these long numbers?

Non-working example:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAJgXBAiIAuBTCBeCA7FB3ByKAFAIwBsATAOxkAsZJAHAKwCUA3AFADGA9lgGdeAGxQA6YbwDmRKGKS8AykjABLLDNYdOnIA

Update:
The integer 1627646185 is intended to represent a time today (not in 1970). How can we get TypeScript to make the time today out of this integer? (JavaScript can do it.)

Comment: You need to use the new keyword when you want to pass in a parameter like that so `var d = new Date(1627646185)`, that should stop the error at least.

Comment: That's what the example does, and the output is always 1970.

Comment: The non-working example is working.

Comment: In the example the number is `1627646185` which is today, but the output is 1970.

Comment: No, `1627646185000` is today. JS Date uses milliseconds not seconds

Comment: The integer `1627646185` is intended to represent a time today (not in 1970). How can we get TypeScript to make the time today out of this integer? (JavaScript can do it.)

Comment: @RichardBarraclough I don't think you read what I said. Let's clarify something first ***TypeScript is never executed***. TS code *compiles into JS*. Anything you run is going to be JavaScript. TS is only around until the compilation-time. With this in mind, the *JavaScript code* that the TS playground executes works correct because the JS Date constructor is *supposed to* parse numbers as milliseconds. If you pass `1627646185` that is `1627646` seconds after the 1st of January 1970.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the number I'm being given is in seconds and not milliseconds, so I need to multiply by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use `new Date(1627646185)` to get the custom date object in typescript. So it will be:

```
let d = new Date(1627646185);
return d.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS `Date` object is based on milliseconds since 1970-01-01:00:00:00Z. But the number `1627646185` if interpreted as milliseconds is just a little less than 19 days. So of course if you do `new Date(1627646185)` it will be `1970-01-19 ...`. Probably this number is the seconds since 1970-01-01:00:00:00Z, and you have to mulitply it by 1000.

And there is another misconception. The [`Date()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#constructor), as you call it in your "working" example, *" returns a string representation of the current date and time*". And it doesn't accept any parameter (and thus ignores any parameter given to it). So If your expected date is today, it may seem to return the expected result, but in fact it doesn't. It returns the current time. See the following snippet, which will print two different timestamp, eventhough using the same number as parameter.

```js
console.log(Date(1627646185));
setTimeout(() => {console.log(Date(1627646185))}, 2000);
```

So to really get the timestamp you are expecting, you have to do call the constructor of `Date` with `new Date(...)` which accepts different parameters (`number` or `string` or another `Date`).

```js
let d = new Date(1627646185000);
console.log(d.toString());
```

If you run these both snippets multiple times, you will see, the timestamps in the first snippet will always change (and display the current time), whereas the timestamp in the second snippet will be the expected one.